# Trouble generating random numbers?

Tags: c++, random

```
rndmBid=rand() % (sellPtr->sellPrice + (1.25*sellPtr->startPrice));
```

whats wrong with this line? Everything is an integer except `1.25` (obviously) and the compiler gives an error which says `invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'.`

I tried changing `startPrice` and `rndmBid` to double, without luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take your pick of the below answers. We pretty much all typed the same thing at the same time. However, I believe the static cast versions are the most correct, mine is doing a standard c-style cast which also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you introduce a `double` into an arithmetic expression, everything gets promoted/converted to double. So you need to convert back to integer:

```
rndmBid = rand() % static_cast<int>( ... );
```

(I trust you realize that your random numbers won't be uniformly distributed.)

Comment: @user2086751: It won't round to the nearest integer; it will round towards zero, even if it's closer to an integer further away from zero.

Comment: @user2086751: no; if you want that, add `0.5` before you convert.

Comment: @KerrekSB what do you mean when you say "random numbers won't be uniformly distributed"??

Answer (score 2):

The rhs is returning a double, while `%` only works on integers. Cast the result into an integer:

```
rand() % static_cast<int>(sellPtr->sellPrice + (1.25 * sellPtr->startPrice));
```

Comment: @user2086751 No, it will simply chop off the fractional part of the result.

Answer (score 2):

`(sellPtr->sellPrice + (1.25*sellPtr->startPrice)` is a double because the result of `(1.25*sellPtr->startPrice)` is a double because `1.25` is a double. Cast the result to int and it will compile:

```
rndmBid=rand() % static_cast<int>(sellPtr->sellPrice + (1.25*sellPtr->startPrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an int to a double, so the result is a double, which cannot be used with the `%` operator.

To fix this, you need to do:

```
rndmBid=rand() % ((int)(sellPtr->sellPrice + (1.25*sellPtr->startPrice)));
```

This will work as long as the double is not bigger than what can fit in an integer.